# Hypothetically speaking

Tags: meaning

If something is hypothetical, then does it imply that it hasn't happened in reality (so far)?

If so,

Context:

Person A does something, let's say "x".

1 hour later

Person A: "Hypothetically speaking, if I did "x", what would you do to me?" Does this imply that the person did not do "x" in the past? If so, isn't this person lying?

Person B: "I would be very mad if you did "x"."

Comment: In my opinion, implying that you didn't do something which you actually did do is lying. However, I don't believe that posing a hypothetical question implies anything either way about whether the hypothetical situation has actually happened in reality.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if you were to post a question about things that are hypothetical, would that mean the post had not happened?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about logic, not English. It probably belongs at [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) or [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Language is a means of communication, but the same set of words can communicate different things - even contradictory things - at different levels.

> **hypothetically** *adverb*
> By imagining a possibility rather than reality; as a hypothesis.
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hypothetically)

At the immediate level, the preface of "hypothetically speaking" marks the communication as merely theoretical, not real.

However, just because someone calls something hypothetical doesn't make it so. Depending on the context, it could even mark something as not really hypothetical. So at the broader level, the "hypothetically speaking" preface can trigger the suspicion that it isn't.

Your question is whether labeling a matter as hypothetical in English is lying if the matter happened to be non-hypothetical.

At the level of pure linguistics, that's making a category error. Hypotheses posit something. Whether the hypothesis is true isn't relevant - the posited condition is merely considered academically.

If we go beyond pure linguistics, we could say that the way the language is used suggests evasiveness. Certainly, phrases like "[hypothetically speaking](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-someone-says-hypothetically-speaking#:%7E:text=Hypothetically%20speaking%2C%20the%20use%20of%20%E2%80%9Chypothetically%20speaking%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D%20means,the%20scenario%20is%20true%20before%20answering%20a%20question.)" and "[asking for a friend](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/asking-for-a-friend#:%7E:text=%22Asking%20for%20a%20Friend%22%20is%20an%20expression%20often,asked%20under%20the%20guise%20of%20a%20helpful%20friend.)" have suffered 'euphemistic degeneration', where the euphemism no longer shields the hearer (and hence no longer shields the speaker) from whatever the more explicit version conveyed. However, going much further than this would bring us beyond the remit of EL&U, so that should be a discussion for a different forum.